# php multi-dimensional arrays remove duplicate based on two values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a rebate system.  The user will check to see if their product qualifies for a rebate by entering the model number, serial number, dealer name,  and purchase date.

If the product qualifies, The values are added to the session array.

```
array(4) { 

[0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["model"]=> string(7) "CP05G10" ["serial"]=> string(9) "ABCK50786" ["pdate"]=> string(10) "2013-05-18" ["amt"]=> string(2) "25" ["dealer"]=> string(8) "79163500" } 

[1]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["model"]=> string(7) "EP24G33" ["serial"]=> string(9) "AAMK01127" ["pdate"]=> string(10) "2013-05-18" ["amt"]=> string(2) "25" ["dealer"]=> string(8) "79163500" } 

[2]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["model"]=> string(7) "CP05G10" ["serial"]=> string(9) "ABCK50786" ["pdate"]=> string(10) "2013-05-17" ["amt"]=> string(2) "25" ["dealer"]=> string(8) "79163500" } 

[3]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["model"]=> string(7) "EP24G33" ["serial"]=> string(9) "AAMK01127" ["pdate"]=> string(10) "2013-05-17" ["amt"]=> string(2) "25" ["dealer"]=> string(8) "79163500" } 

}
```

The problem I am having is users are adding the same model numbers and serial numbers but a different purchase date or dealer.  Which creates duplicates in the system.

What I am needing is to remove duplicates based on the model numbers and serial numbers.

I have implemented the suggestion:

```
    //echo $amount;
        if ($amount != ''){
            $rebate[] = $tmprebate = array("id" => '', "model" => $model_number, "serial" => $serial_number, "pdate" => $purchase_date, "amt" => $amount, "dealer" => $dealerid);
        }else{
            $noRebate[] = $tmprebate = array("id" => '', "model" => $model_number, "serial" => $serial_number, "pdate" => $purchase_date);
        }

    if( isset($_SESSION['rebate']) ){
       foreach($_SESSION['rebate'] as $session )
        { 
           if($session['serial'] != $serial_number && $session['model'] != $model_number){
               $_SESSION['rebate'] = $rebate;
               $_SESSION['noRebate'] = $noRebate;
            }
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['rebate']   = $rebate;
        $_SESSION['noRebate'] = $noRebate;
    }
```

I re-implemented the suggested code and all is working.

```
        // check to see if model and serial already exist in Session
        if( isset($_SESSION['rebate'])){

           $match_rebate = 0;
           foreach($_SESSION['rebate'] as $session )
            {  
               if($session['serial'] == $serial_number && $session['model'] == $model_number){ // if session matches what is being submitted
                   $match_rebate = 1;
                }
            }
        }else{
            $_SESSION['rebate']   = $rebate;
            $_SESSION['noRebate'] = $noRebate;
        }

        if($match_rebate == 0)
        {
          $_SESSION['rebate']   = $rebate;
          $_SESSION['noRebate'] = $noRebate;
        }
```

Comment: Mother of formatting.

Comment: @ChrisCooney: Editing instead of placing a witty comment would have been more helpful.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It was edited soon after I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing Duplicates based on the model numbers and serial numbers, check whether the model number and serial number exists in the session array before creating the sessions. If found you can avoid creating the session or else create one.
Tweaking your code

```
if ($amount != ''){
        $rebate[] = $tmprebate = array("id" => '', "model" => $model_number, "serial" => $serial_number, "pdate" => $purchase_date, "amt" => $amount, "dealer" => $dealerid);
    }else{
        $noRebate[] = $tmprebate = array("id" => '', "model" => $model_number, "serial" => $serial_number, "pdate" => $purchase_date);
    }

if( isset($_SESSION['rebate'])){

   $match_rebate = 0;
   foreach($_SESSION['rebate'] as $session )
    {  
       if($session['serial'] == $serial_number && $session['model'] == $model_number){
           $match_rebate = 1;
        }
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['rebate']   = $rebate;
}
if( isset($_SESSION['norebate'])){

   $match_norebate = 0;
   foreach($_SESSION['norebate'] as $session2 )
    {  
       if($session2['serial'] == $serial_number && $session2['model'] == $model_number){
           $match_norebate = 1;
        }
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['noRebate'] = $noRebate;
}

if($match_rebate == 0)
{
  array_push($_SESSION['rebate'],$rebate);
}    

if($match_norebate == 0)
{
  array_push($_SESSION['norebate'],$noRebate);
}
```

Comment: @user2091928: Instead of editing my post, update your question with your solution or comment under my post. I reviewed your code and I know where the problem lies. I will be able to answer if you have it updated in your question or in comment.

Comment: I have implemented the above recommendation and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Please post your implemented code again so that everyone can view.

Comment: Just remove `else{
           $_SESSION['rebate']   = $rebate;
           $_SESSION['noRebate'] = $noRebate;
    }` suggested in your edit. That should do the trick

Comment: When after I removed the else if Session is NULL nothing gets added.

Comment: nothing should be added right! then only duplicate entries can be prevented.

Comment: If the serial and model is already in session don't add.  if it is NOT there add it.

Comment: are you sure session is null? can you post here `print_r($_SESSION);` values

Comment: NULL Array ( [noRebate] => ) is what print_r($_SESSION) displays,

Comment: ok.. now post here what print_r($_SESSION); displays after adding else(updated answer). Try with two duplicate entries and one non duplicate and post here result of print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: Array ( [noRebate] => [rebate] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => [model] => EP24G33 [serial] => AAMK01127 [pdate] => 2013-05-18 [amt] => 25 [dealer] => 79163500 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => [model] => CP05G10 [serial] => ABCK50786 [pdate] => 2013-05-18 [amt] => 25 [dealer] => 79163500 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => [model] => EP24G33 [serial] => AAMK01127 [pdate] => 2013-05-07 [amt] => 25 [dealer] => 79163500 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => [model] => CP05G10 [serial] => ABCK50786 [pdate] => 2013-05-14 [amt] => 25 [dealer] => 79163500 ) ) )

Comment: I implemented your modified code:  Array ( [noRebate] => [rebate] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => [model] => EP24G33 [serial] => AAMK01127 [pdate] => 2013-05-18 [amt] => 25 [dealer] => 79163500 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => [model] => CP05G10 [serial] => ABCK50786 [pdate] => 2013-05-18 [amt] => 25 [dealer] => 79163500 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => [model] => CP05G10 [serial] => ABCK50786 [pdate] => 2013-05-02 [amt] => 25 [dealer] => 79163500 ) ) )

Comment: The issue is that it is looping through all the serial and model numbers and comparing it to the one that is being submitted. For Example:  Serial # xxx and Serial #YYY have already been submitted.  then someone tries to submit Serial #XXX again.  It will fail on Serial #XXX but will pass on Serial #YYY and resubmit.

Comment: @user2091928: found the flaw in my code and updated the answer!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. How do you get the unique serial number and model numbers that are currently in session and then compare with what is being submitted>